# RxJava2: TestSubscriber.AssertNoErrors always pass

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rx-java2

I am testing some features of Rxjava2(2.0.7)
and have some troubles in unit test

here is my code

```
    RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(null);
    Observable<String> o = Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<String>) e -> {
        String s = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
        System.out.println("runing observable@" + s);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    o
            .doOnNext(x -> {
                System.out.println(x);
                throw new RuntimeException();
            })
            .doOnError(e->e.printStackTrace())
            .test()
            .assertNoErrors()
            .awaitCount(1)
            .awaitDone(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The problem is this test always passed, but I can still find exception printed in log

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to switch the order of execution, and put the `assertNoErrors()` at the end.

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(null);
    Observable<String> o = Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<String>) e -> {
        String s = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
        System.out.println("runing observable@" + s);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    })
            .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    o
            .doOnNext(x -> {
                System.out.println(x);
                throw new RuntimeException();
            })
            .doOnError(e -> e.printStackTrace())
            .test()
            .awaitCount(1)
            .awaitDone(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .assertNoErrors();
```

otherwise `assertNoErrors()` act immediately after you call the `test()` operator and the error still didn't propagate in the stream.
Genrally, you should first act with `awaitXXX` to wait for some expected event to happen, and then test it with `assertXXX`.